# Create configuration file - ability to read and save changes

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I know I can't save data to file with javascript, but is there any solution to create configuration file (JSON) on local file system where I can write data, make some changes like add or remove object and save this. I don't want lose my new data when i next time starts my app. Any ideas?

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

I want to use it on different computers.

Comment: I want to keep config on local file system.

Comment: May be use mongodb to store in JSON

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is what you require here. Or look at [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write yourself a `SettingsService` to read and write the data via the `localstorage`:

```ts
class SettingsEntry {
    constructor(public key: string, public value: any) { }
}

export class SettingsService {
    private SETTINGS_KEY = "__SETTINGS__";
    private _settings: Array<SettingsEntry>;

    constructor() {
        let settings = localStorage.getItem(this.SETTINGS_KEY);

        if (settings && settings != undefined) {
            this._settings = JSON.parse(settings);
        }
        else {
            this._settings = [];

            this.save();
        }
    }

    private indexOf(key: string): number {
        for (let i = 0; i < this._settings.length; i++) {
            if (this._settings[i].key == key) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private save() {
        localStorage.setItem(this.SETTINGS_KEY, JSON.stringify(this._settings));
    }

    get(key: string) {
        let index: number = this.indexOf(key);

        if (index >= 0) {
            return this._settings[index].value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    set(key: string, value: any) {
        let index: number = this.indexOf(key);

        if (index >= 0) {
            this._settings[index].value = value;
        }
        else {
            this._settings.push(new SettingsEntry(key, value));
        }

        this.save();
    }
}
```

Use it like this in your components or services:

```ts
_settingsService.set("time", new Date());

let time = _settingsService.get("time");
```

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M7EGq2X9mnvveicXfHcz?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Thanks for answer! I like this idea and I will use it 100% for personal settings, but i need something else for global settings when i want work on other computer.